# CSS: Deselected tabs jump from top to bottom

Tags: html, css, radio-button

### The problem

I have built a popup that handles multiple tabs (= radio-inputs). The formatting of my tabs works just fine, however, if I select a tab, the remaining ones will be aligned below the box and not above it. See the two images below.

### My current solution

[image: If the last tab is selected, I get the desired format]
[image: If the first tab is selected, the remaining boxes go to the bottom]

### What I tried so far

I think that it has something to do with some inconsistencies between `label:before` and `label:after` in my CSS. I tried to switch from `width: 100%` to `width: fit-content` because I thought that the labels potentially cover all the space to the right. However, this didn't help. That's why I would kindly ask you to help me out with my problem.

### The (reduced) code

##### HTML

```css
.tab-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00000050;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-wrapper input {
    display: none;
}

.tab-wrapper label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-wrapper + label:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 0;
    z-index:10;
}

.tab-wrapper label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-wrapper input:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-wrapper input:checked + label:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

#content0, #content1, #content2, #content3, #content4 {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

#tab0:checked ~ #content0,
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}
```

```html
<div className="tab-wrapper">
  <input className="tabs" id="tab0" name="tabs" type="radio" checked="true" />
  <label for="tab0">
    luca5
  </label>
  <div id="content0">
    <h3>Some dummy content</h3>
  </div>
  <input className="tabs" id="tab1" name="tabs" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab1">
    luca3
  </label>
  <div id="content1">
    <h3>Some dummy content</h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

##### CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change the position of your second input (and label). When you show the first `DIV` the normal alignment of the DOM move your input below the `DIV`.

```css
.tab-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #00000050;
    padding-top: 10%;
    padding-left: 20%;
    padding-right: 20%;
    width: 100%;
}

.tab-wrapper input {
    display: none;
}

.tab-wrapper label {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 15px 25px;
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
    margin-bottom: -5px;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-wrapper + label:before {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 15px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -11px;
    left: 0;
    z-index:10;
}

.tab-wrapper label:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
}

.tab-wrapper input:checked + label {
    position: relative;
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
}

.tab-wrapper input:checked + label:after {
    display: block;
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
}

#content0, #content1, #content2, #content3, #content4 {
    display: none;
    background-color: white;
    padding: 15px;
    border-radius: 0 8px 8px 8px;
}

#tab0:checked ~ #content0,
#tab1:checked ~ #content1,
#tab2:checked ~ #content2,
#tab3:checked ~ #content3,
#tab4:checked ~ #content4 {
    display: block;
    box-shadow: 0 0 15px #939393;
}
```

```html
<div className="tab-wrapper">
  <input className="tabs" id="tab0" name="tabs" type="radio" checked="true" />
  <label for="tab0">
    luca5
  </label>
  <input className="tabs" id="tab1" name="tabs" type="radio" />
  <label for="tab1">
    luca3
  </label>
  <div id="content0">
    <h3>Some dummy content 1 </h3>
  </div>
  <div id="content1">
    <h3>Some dummy content 2 </h3>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, it solved my problem!